# displays as undefined if person dosen't chat discord js v12

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

[Image of users displaying as undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4k2t.png)
I wan't to display **usernames** instead of pinging user in the leaderboard embed?
At this point i have no idea what to do i asked people to help and couldn't figure it out. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4pW3.png) it says undefined until member chats.

> Leaberboard command file

```
         let UserJSON = JSON.parse(Fs.readFileSync("./DataBase/users.json"));
        var Sorted = Object.entries(UserJSON).sort((a, b) => b[1].money- a[1].money);
        if (Sorted.length > 10) Sorted = Sorted.slice(0, 10);

        var LBString = "";
        Sorted.forEach(user => {
            LBString += `${client.users.cache.find(u => u.id == user[0])} - ${user[1].money}\n`;
        });
        var LBEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#FFFFFF')
            .setTitle("**Coins Leaderboard**")
            .setDescription(LBString);
        message.channel.send(LBEmbed);
        client.channels.cache.get('941016208940077086').send(`${message.author.username} has used $coinslb`)


//users.json file
{"599675959888707594":{"money":492,"lastbeg":1644580691540,"lastwork":1644580757380},"617797297924866093":{"money":0,"lastbeg":0,"lastwork":0}}
```

> I want the leaderboard to display usernames not @ them in the embed

Comment: Can you please tell us more information in the body of your question? Your title should not be the full text, and your body should not only contain code. Please edit your question for this. Thanks!

Comment: umm what about now?

Comment: That is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After `user[0])`, put `.username` to get only the username, like this:

```js
LBString += `${client.users.cache.find(u => u.id == user[0]).username} - ${user[1].money}\n`;
```

Also, it shows `undefined` when they haven't chatted before because they aren't in your database. You could get the guild (server) you're in and fetch the member by ID, instead of from cache:

```js
guild.members.fetch('user_id_here').username;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I  noticed that if you add it **AFTER** there is anything in users.json it will be displayed as undefined so when you add the .username you  need to reset ur users.json